# Sequelize issue interting rows on tables with triggers

Tags: sql-server, node.js, triggers, sequelize.js

I'm currently working with SQL Server and Sequelize on a project. I'm facing a problem when trying to insert rows in a table that has a trigger associated with it.

I was able to find this information about the problem https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3284

I have downloaded the .js files and what it says is that it works with a temp table to overcome this issue:

> SequelizeDatabaseError: The target table 'tableA' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.

This solution is not working for me, I have issues when trying to re use the object that were interseted and can't access to all of the variables.

Is there any other walk around for this issue?

This is my code:

```
  return Person.create( {   lastName: options.lastName,
                            name: options.name,
                         }, {transaction: t}).then(
                                function (person) {
                                        return Student.create({  id                 :person.id,
                                                                numberRecord              :'PF-'+person.id,

                                                            }, {transaction: t}).then(function (student) {
                                                return Shoots.create({  id                  : person.id,
                                                                            numberRecord              :'PF-'+person.id
                                                    }, {transaction: t}).then(function (record) {



                                                            return StudentContract.create({
                                                                PersonID              :person.id,
                                                                dateStart:'2016021 00:00:00.000',
                                                                endDate:'20161231 00:00:00.000',}
                                                                , {transaction: t}).then(function (contract) {
                                                                return student;

                                                            });

                                                    });
                                        });

                                        });

        }).then(function (result) {
    // Transaction has been committed
    // result is whatever the result of the promise chain returned to the transaction callback is
    console.log(result);
    cb(null, result);
}).catch(function (err) {
    // Transaction has been rolled back
    // err is whatever rejected the promise chain returned to the transaction callback is
    console.error(+err);
    cb(err, "Transaction Failed");
});
```

When using the solution provided in the link above, it says that it can't find the 'id' property. 'id' is defined in Person and Student as the primary key.

Any ideas or official solution from sequelize to work this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention that the table that has the trigger enabled is the last one: StudentContract. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Set `hasTrigger` to true when defining the table, and Sequelize will take care of this for you. For example:

```
sequelize.define(TABLE_NAME,
{
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  description: {
    type: Sequelize.VARCHAR(8000)
  }
},
{
  // options
  timestamps: false,
  hasTrigger: true
});
```

Comment: on sequelize, this doesnt work when working on soft delete.. i still finding how to prevent output clause when do soft deleting

Answer (score 0):

I have read your question and I understood that you need to capture what you inserted. And yes it is possible to capture the inserted data with table variable.

Try below, hope it will help atleast to get some other idea.

```
    DECLARE @IDENTITY_CAPTURE TABLE (INSERTED_IDENTITY BIGINT, INSERTED_BASE_NME VARCHAR(20))

    INSERT INTO SALESORDER  
    OUTPUT INSERTED.SALESORDER_NBR, INSERTED.SALESORDER_NME  INTO @IDENTITY_CAPTURE
    SELECT 1, 'PICSART'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'IMAX'
```

Then you can query on Table variable to get the data inserted.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry for not getting it, but where should I add this statement that you are posting?